# How can I get the Whole Message Without Closing Connection -- Resulting in Possibility to Get Multiple Messages?

Tags: python, sockets

I currently have a server at public IP: `IP`. I can use this Client Code to connect to the Server and establish a connection between the two.

**Client.py**

```
import socket
import select
import multiprocessing

class ClientAdminConnection:

    # Port 80
    def __init__(self):
        self.ports = [80]
        print("Ports: {}".format(self.ports))
        self.sockets = []
        self.createConnectionToServer()

        # Multithread Listening
        processes = []
        for socket in self.sockets:
            print("Creating Process")
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.startListeningForCommands, args=(socket,))
            processes.append(process)
        for process in processes:
            print("Starting Process")
            process.start()

    def createConnectionToServer(self):
        for port in self.ports:
            client_admin_port = ('IP', port)

            client_admin_socket = socket.socket()
            
            # Connect to Server
            client_admin_socket.connect(client_admin_port)
            print("Connected to {}".format(client_admin_port))

            self.sockets.append(client_admin_socket)

    def startListeningForCommands(self, socket):
        print("Listening")
        
        wholeMsg = ""
        while True:
            data = socket.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                print("No data")
                break
            else:
                dataBit = data.decode("utf-8")
                print("There is Data: {}".format(dataBit))
                wholeMsg += dataBit
                
        print("Message: {}".format(wholeMsg))
```

I'd like to be able to send multiple messages and have the client listening after I `.connect()`

Currently, I can get it where I can read the data bit. But, I'd like to be able to send 1 message - see the entire thing (even if longer than 1024 bytes) and then send another message. Right now - I can only see the dataBits that come in. I never get to see `wholeMsg`. Generally, most of my messages are small - but I would like to use an arbitrary size and still see the entire message every time one is sent over the connection.

**Current Results:**

> Ports: [80]

> Connected to ('34.207.93.146', 80)

> Creating Process

> Starting Process

> Listening

> There is Data: Mary Had A Little Lamb

Mary Had A Little Lamb is sent from the server.

**What I Expect:**

> Ports: [80]

> Connected to ('34.207.93.146', 80)

> Creating Process

> Starting Process

> Listening

> There is Data: Mary Had A Little Lamb

> Message: Mary Had A Little Lamb *THIS SECTION IS MISSING

Comment: Have you searched for a solution to the problem? What were the results?

Comment: Yeah - most of the answers I get are for a single set of 1024 bytes - not how to continuously read messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP is a stream-oriented connection.  It is not packet-oriented.  A single transmission might be chopped into several pieces, or concatenated with other unread data.  YOU have to establish a way to know when a message is finished, such as a `\n`.  That way, the receiver keeps reading, and appending to the message buffer, until it sees the `\n`.

Comment: Is it as simple as a `\n` to determine that a packet has ended? Furthermore, do you have any information/sources regarding the best practices to start and end a message? Ex: I want to send "I have a tattoo" would I just encase that inside "\nI have a tattoo\n"?

Comment: It's up to you to create whatever protocol works for you.  Sometimes, people send a byte count first, so they know how much is coming.  If it's line-oriented data, it's often easy to send a `\n` at the end, so you can just keep reading until you have a `\n`.  Remember that if two messages are combined, you might get two `\n`s that you have to split.

Comment: Why would you get a situation if two messages are combined? Specifically for UDP?

Comment: You aren't talking about UDP.  UDP **is** packet oriented.  If you send an 80-byte msg and a 40-byte msg, the receiver will get two messages, one of 80 and one of 40.  TCP doesn't do that.  TCP will smash them together if the receiver didn't read the first before the second arrived.

Comment: Ahh - yes yes. Jeez laweez - too many things, my bad. You're right. So if I have send a message say 80 bytes (40 byte limit) - each `.recv` will have a `\n`? Or just the 2nd one?

Comment: It's whatever YOU decide to do.  The network's not going to add it.  The receiver will receive whatever you send, just not in the same size chunks.  YOU need to decide how to help your receiver chop them back into pieces.  If you want the receiver to see two messages, and you're sending text, then `\n` is a convenient way to do it.

Comment: It's exactly like writing lines to a file that you want to read back later.  The file is one big stream of bytes.  If you read in 1,024 bytes at a time, how do reconstruct the individual lines that were written?

Comment: I see. I really appreciate your help! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate Tim's answer, but wanted to highlight some simple concepts that I was missing as a new socket-eer in hopes of anyone else trying to understand.

```
def startListeningForCommands(self, socket):
        print("Listening")
        
        wholeMsg = ""
        while True:
            data = socket.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                print("No data")
                break
            else:
                dataBit = data.decode("utf-8")
                print("There is Data: {}".format(dataBit))
                wholeMsg += dataBit
```

The above won't work in the sense that `wholeMsg` will never get called because

```
while True:
    data = socket.recv(1024)
```

will continuously portion out segments of data into 1024 bytes IF there is data obtained. It is to the programmer's discretion to determine when a whole message has been received. This is where headers and footers come into play (to my understanding). But, there will never not be `data`, assuming the socket is open and listening.

For example, you would get:

> Listening

> "There is Data: I am the first message"

> "There is Data: I am the second message"

If there was more than 1024 bytes, say 1200 bytes it would be

> "There is Data: 'First 1024 bytes'"

> "There is Data: 'Next 176 bytes'"

> "There is Data: I am the second message"

It is up to you to determine where the start of one message is and the end of that message. How you do that... I am still researching. Just wanted to help out anyone else struggling with that concept.